# more than 3 itesm in android bottom navigation menu using design support library

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-menu, bottomnavigationview

I am using android design support library V 25.0.0 to create bottom navigation menu. i have configured 5 items in menu . but only 3 items are shown with title. I want all 5 items to be shown with icons and title .

is anyone able to achieve this?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="@string/menu_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search" />
 <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/menu_settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_add" />
   ....... three more items
```

layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"        android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
app:menu="@menu/bottom_bar_tabs"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i have got five items with icons and title. but only three bottom menu items with tile are shown